# Loading ROMS to Emu OS

Tags: linux, emulation

I recently downloaded Emu OS (a Linux distro) and installed it within virtual box. Everything works fine but I am unable to actually run the roms within an emulator. I tried a GBC rom that is in .zip format and I copied and pasted it into the GB and GBC folder, but the emulator itself isn;t able to recognize it. Does anyone have any experience with this or have gotten it to work?

Comment: The one for Gameboy Color. There is only one on EmuOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One must simply drag the ROM file to the directory that is associated with the respective emulator. This can be done via the file manager. Afterwards, reboot and select the emulator that you desire and your game should show up in the list.

Note that EmuOS is extremely old and no longer maintained. RetroPi is a good alternative and putting ROMs on that is the same as EmuOS.